# Node.js Connection mongodb using mongoclient

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

In node JS I just wanted to write some external method which retrieves the data from mongodb and return it. In that I had use `MongoClient.js` module for interacting with`mongodb`. But the problem is when calling the external method, it returns value before the database connection method completes execution. Here I just want to hold my return statement until `mongodb.connect` method was completed. what to do?
Here my code follows,

**service.js**

```
var employee = require('./model/employeeService.js');
var json = employee.getUser(employeeId);
```

Where employeeService acts as model which interacts with database and return the data into service.js where our web services written and it responds to user.

**employeeService.js**

```
exports.getUser = function(employeeId) {
    var json = [];
    MongoClient.connect(db.getdbUrl(),function(err,db){
        if(err) {
            json = err; 
         }else {
            document = (employeeId)?{_id:employeeId}:{};
            db.collection('Employee').find(document).limit(50).toArray(function(err,users){
            if(err) {
                json = err;
            }
            else {
                    console.log("Inside MongoClient"); // this will executes second
                    json = users;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log("OutSide",json);   // this executes first
    return json;
}
```

Here I can find asynchronous execution flow of connect MongoClient.connect method from my output console and getting empty array by calling it from service.js.

**Output Console**

```
OutSide []
Inside MongoClient
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `not` the abnormal flow, this is how the `asynchronous` code executes. if you want to return the users, return it inside `else{}`, Replace `json = users;` by `return users;` and remove return at the end of your code.

And go learn some more stuff about `Asynchrounous vs Synchrounous` calls and how they execute. And also consider learning `callback` in Javascript.